# Access Friends Email address of twitter who is logged in through my app

Tags: android, twitter

I am trying to find the code where I want to access the email address of a user's friends. Suppose a user logged in to my app via Twitter, then I want to get all the friends list along with email address. I got a code from https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE. In this I am able to get the list of user's friends, but not able to get friends Email address.

Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Till now, Twitter doesn't provide you the email response in any of REST/Streaming API.

But, requesting a User’s Email Address requires your application to be whitelisted by Twitter. To request access, you need to go [here.](https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform)

Then you can [request a User's email address](https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/request-user-email-address.html) it in Twitter's Fabric by,

```
TwitterAuthClient authClient = new TwitterAuthClient();
authClient.requestEmail(session, new Callback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Result<String> result) {
        // Do something with the result, which provides the email address
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
      // Do something on failure
    }
});
```

Comment: I did all this. I am getting email address. But this email address is of user who is logged in. I want user's friend email address. Not just user's email.

Comment: I doubt if this is really possible.

Comment: Yeah Twitter's API has been slow on the uptake with emails... I don't think this is possible yet if you're wanting to user their API

Comment: I have a requirement where a user register to my App via Twitter. After registering I want to access that user's friends email address and post something on friend's wall like eg: advertising my app.   Can I do this????

Comment: Nooooo..Not at all. Say there is no feasibility.

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna need to get your app [whitelisted](https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform).

Comment: This should be in comment.

Comment: I request for that and got permission to get email address of user who is logging in. But I am not able to get user's friends email address.